# Extracting raster point values in CSV along with coordinates in GEE

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, time-series, sentinel-1

I am trying to extract timeseries Sentinel1 value to a CSV file. Using the code below I have generated graph and also exported to csv but the coordinates ares missing. Please check my code and suggest me how to append coordinates in CSV

```
var S1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
// Loading shape file
var points = ee.FeatureCollection("users/tilok/pts")
//Selecting bands
var image_collection = S1.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-28')
.filterBounds(points);

// Reduce & Make a Chart
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: image_collection,
  regions: points, 
  band: 'VH',
  reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),  
  scale:10, });
print(chart);

Map.centerObject(points);
Map.addLayer(points,{color:'yellow'}, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To correctly extract the raster information for a `featureCollection` you need to use `sampleRegions`. The first step is transforming the time series collection into a multiband raster, where each band corresponds to each image of the time series. Aftwerwards, you need to use `sampleRegions` to extract the raster values and using the argument `geometry: true` so that a geometry for each feature is returned. Finally, you need to transform the geometry into a simple table by obtaining the geometry coordinates and afterwards, eliminate them.

```
// Transform image collection of VH band into image with n bands
var timeSeries = ee.ImageCollection(image_collection.select('VH')).toBands()
  // Set masked values as -11000, set sameFootprint as false to override original image footprint (useful for working in areas with several tiles)
  .unmask({value: 0, sameFootprint: false});
  
// Extract data for each point
var sampledReg = ee.Image(timeSeries)
      .sampleRegions({
        // Get the sample from the points FeatureCollection.
        collection: points,
        // Properties from the points collection to pass on to the sampled info
        //properties: ['id'],
        // Set the scale to get Sentinel pixels in the FeatureCollection.
        scale: 30,
        tileScale: 8,
        // Return geometries
        geometries: true
      });

// Transform coordinates into properties in the table.
var featColExport = sampledReg.map(function (feature) {
  // Get geometry
  var coordinates = feature.geometry()
                          // Transform it to the desired EPSG code. Here WGS 84
                          .transform('epsg:4326')
                          // Get coordinates as a list
                          .coordinates();
  // Get both entries of coordinates and set them as new properties
  var resul = feature.set('lon', coordinates.get(0), 
                     'lat', coordinates.get(1));
  // Remove geometry                   
  return resul.setGeometry(null);
});

// Export table as csv
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: featColExport,
    description: 'pointsExtractCoords',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
});
```